# PayPal get and hold token for future use

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to have a user fill in a PayPal form and get a token that can be used to buy items for the user without further user input?

EX: User wants to buy an item, but the price is not to their liking. The user sets a bot to buy the item for them when the price falls to more acceptable price.

I know that I will use the PayPal API and will need my own token/id for the bot as well as the actual user's token/id to make payments on their behalf. I was just wondering if there might be something else I missed?

Comment: If you want this to work without user input, I think you may either need to place a cookie (which I wouldn't recommend due to _so many_ potential problems), or you may want to built a system where the user can make a profile and log in, and you can hold the token in their account on your server (which would be a lot more secure, assuming your server is secure).

Comment: You can try using Preapproval Payments. Check out the documentation here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/

Comment: @Tijmen I am currently working on a user profile. So you say that there is a user token I would be able to save for future uses?

Comment: @CCamilo Thank you for the link. I will research the page and steps and see if it is what I need.

Comment: @pypenko As far as I know, it should be possible to save the token, but CCamilo's idea is probably better.